# Scaling progress bar value

Tags: c++, progress-bar

Im setting up a progress bar as follows :

```
void CProgressBar::add(int ammount)
{
    mProgress += ammount;
}

float CProgressBar::get()
{
    float pr = (float)mProgress * 100.0f / (float)mMax;
    return pr;
}
```

And now here is the problem.I'm trying to render a small surface although it doesn't properly fill it because i can't
figure out how to scale properly the value :

```
/*
    Progress bar box has size of 128x16
    |-----------|
    |-----------|
*/
float progress = progressBar->get();
float scale = 4.0f; //Here i have it hardcoded although i have to make this generic

progress *= scale;
graphics->color(prgColor);
graphics->renderQd(CRect(x,y,progress,height));
```

So im kindly asking for some help on the matter...

Comment: This is a C++ question, not a C,C# or anything else question. Kindly select the relevant tags ONLY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to linearly interpolate between the width of the rectangle with 0% progress and the width of the rectangle with 100% progress. E.G:

```
float width_0 = 0.f; // or any other number of pixels
float width_100 = 250.f; // or any other number of pixels
```

The interpolation works as follows:

```
float interpolated_width = (width_100 - width_0) * progress + width_0;
```

Important: `progress` has to be in the range of 0 to 1! So you might want to change the `CProgressBar::get()` function or divide by 100 first.

Now you can just render the rectangle with the new width:

```
graphics->renderQd(CRect(x,y,interpolated_width,height));
```

Comment: Thanks , i tried it although it didn't make any difference :(

Comment: @user1010005: what is the problem? what exactly does not work?

Comment: Never mind , got it to work. I fixed it by specifying the pixel units per character and then multiplying it with scale.

Answer (score 0):

The width of your progress bar is 128 and the progress->get() function returns something between 0 and 100 therefore, without knowing your library details, it appears your scale should be 1.28

I assume mMax is the value of complete progress.

For little tidy-up I would make `get()` const and not use C-style casts.

Comment: Thanks , but seems like 1.28 isn't enough for it.

Comment: And yes nMax is the maximum value

Comment: I fixed it by specifying the pixel units per character and then multiplying it with scale.

Comment: It always helps to get your units correct. Interestingly that was one of the topic points Bjarne Stroustrup made in his first presentation at the Going Native conference.